# Reach html elements name using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I searched on internet for "popup picture" and I found a webpage with this source code

```
<div class="popup-gallery">
<a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8242/8558295633_f34a55c1c6_b.jpg" title="The Cleaner">
    <img src="popup/8558295633_f34a55c1c6_s.jpg" height="75" width="75">
</a>
<a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8382/8558295631_0f56c1284f_b.jpg" title="Winter Dance">
    <img src="popup/8558295631_0f56c1284f_s.jpg" height="75" width="75">
</a>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.albumsgallery').magnificPopup({
          delegate: 'a',
          type: 'image',
          tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
          mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
          gallery: {
            enabled: true,
            navigateByImgClick: true,
            preload: [0,1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
          },
          image: {
            tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.',
            titleSrc: function(item) {
              return item.el.attr('title');
            }
          }
        });
      });
</script>
```

what i want is to modify the `jquery` code to fit my `HTML` code

```
  <div class="albumsgallery">
<ul>
  <li><a class="albumspic" href="images/test.gif"><img src="images/test.gif" alt="gallary picture" title="gallary picture" /><div class="albumtitle">Album1</div></a></li>
  <li><a class="albumspic" href="images/test.gif"><img src="images/test.gif" alt="gallary picture" title="gallary picture" /><div class="albumtitle">Album2</div></a></li>
  <li><a class="albumspic" href="images/test.gif"><img src="images/test.gif" alt="gallary picture" title="gallary picture" /><div class="albumtitle">Album3</div></a></li>
  <li><a class="albumspic" href="images/test.gif"><img src="images/test.gif" alt="gallary picture" title="gallary picture" /><div class="albumtitle">Album4</div></a></li>
  <li><a class="albumspic" href="images/test.gif"><img src="images/test.gif" alt="gallary picture" title="gallary picture" /><div class="albumtitle">Album5</div></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Could you please explain how can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the website you found is using a plugin : [magnificPopup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html).

So go there and adapt *your* HTML to the plugin's required markup... not the opposite ;)

From [MagnificPopup's documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html) :

```
<div class="parent-container">
  <a href="path-to-image-1.jpg">Open popup 1</a>
  <a href="path-to-image-2.jpg">Open popup 2</a>
  <a href="path-to-image-3.jpg">Open popup 3</a>
</div>
```